How to Properly Change the Database URI in Flask-SQLAlchemy for Failover Handling?
I am using Flask-SQLAlchemy to connect to a MariaDB database. I've configured the database URI in my .env file. I want to implement a failover mechanism so that if the connection to MariaDB fails, it switches to an SQLite database for testing purposes.

Here is the code I'm using to set up the database:

#uri 1
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = config('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI')

migrate = Migrate()

db.init_app(app)
migrate.init_app(app, db)

with app.app_context():
    try:
        db.create_all()
    except Exception as e:
        app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "sqlite:///database_temp/database.db" #uri2 for failover
        db.engine.dispose()
        migrate.init_app(app, db)
        db.create_all()

Note: My variable db = SQLAlchemy() is located in a folder named models. Additionally, when my application context attempts to use db.create_all(), the exception occurs but within the exception handling, it still uses the same URI or in other cases, it says that a connection already exists and that I should use that one for Flask.
What I tried: I configured SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI to switch to SQLite if the MariaDB Server connection fails. I also called db.engine.dispose() to release the current engine and reinitialized SQLAlchemy and Migrate after changing the URI.
What I expected to happen: I expected that if the connection to MariaDB Server fails, the application would switch to using SQLite as specified in SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, and db.create_all() would work with the new SQLite database.
What actually resulted: The application still tries to connect to MariaDB uri and gives an error stating that a connection fail, or already exists or that it should use the existing connection, even though the URI was changed to SQLite in the exception handling.

When you initialize the SQLAlchemy object, it creates a connection to the database specified in the SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI configuration. Even if you change the SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI later, the existing connection remains active.
To achieve the failover mechanism you described, you need to recreate the SQLAlchemy object with the new URI.
Something like this:
#uri 1
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = config('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI')

db = None
try:
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)
    migrate = Migrate()
    migrate.init_app(app, db)
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
except Exception as e:
    # Failover to SQLite
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "sqlite:///database_temp/database.db"  # uri2 for failover
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)  # Recreate the SQLAlchemy object with the new URI
    migrate = Migrate()
    migrate.init_app(app, db)
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()


Thanks for the suggestion. However, I encountered a cyclic import issue when trying to create the SQLAlchemy object in app/main.py. To address this, I moved the creation of the SQLAlchemy instance to a function called create_new(app) in app/models/db.py. This function handles the creation and initialization of the SQLAlchemy object.

However, when using this function, I receive the error "SQLAlchemy has already been registered on this Flask App."

Can you move the initializer to a separate module? If so, you can create a factory function to create the flask app and handle failover logics inside the factory function.

I couldn't find a way to dynamically change the URI in SQLAlchemy, so instead, I implemented a method to check if a port is active via sockets, and if it is not active, I handle the failover accordingly.
# Fail over, need re and socket modules...
re_ip=r'(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})'
def check_port(ip, port):
    ip=re.search(re_ip,ip).group(0) 
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.settimeout(1)
        result = s.connect_ex((ip, port))
        if result == 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False

if check_port(config('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'), 3306):
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = config('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI')
    db.init_app(app)
else:
    print("FAILOVER START.")
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "sqlite:///database.db"
    db.init_app(app)


It seems like you're facing an issue with the failover mechanism not properly switching to the SQLite database when the MariaDB connection fails. There are a few key points to address:
Ensure Proper Disconnection and Reinitialization:
When switching the URI, it's important to properly dispose of the existing SQLAlchemy engine and reinitialize both SQLAlchemy and Migrate. Simply changing the URI and calling dispose() might not be sufficient.
Ensure Application Context:
Make sure that your changes are happening within the same application context.
